# How to apply Jump and gravity in java

Tags: java

Hey guys I'm working in a game where I want a jump function and gravity function
instead of my player just flying around in the air. I added the function of able to press 'Space Bar' but haven't assigned any values to it and I don't know how.

Basically all I want is a simple jump function and gravity function.

This code below is my Key Manager(my keyboard inputs)

```js
package com.vescorspel.game.MyFirstGame.input;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class KeyManager implements KeyListener{
 
 private boolean[] keys;
 public boolean up, down, left, right, jump;
 
 public KeyManager(){
  keys = new boolean[256];
 }
 
 public void tick(){
  up = keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];
  down = keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];
  left = keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
  right = keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
  jump = keys[KeyEvent.VK_SPACE]; 
 }

 @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
  System.out.println("Pressed!");
 }

 @Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
 }

 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
  
 }

}
```

My Player code for my player.

```js
package com.vescorspel.game.MyFirstGame.entities.creatures;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import com.vescorspel.game.MyFirstGame.Handler;
import com.vescorspel.game.MyFirstGame.gfx.Animation;
import com.vescorspel.game.MyFirstGame.gfx.Assets;

public class Player extends Creatures{
 
 //Animations
 private Animation animDino;
 
 public Player(Handler handler, float x, float y) {
  super(handler, x, y, Creatures.DEFAULT_CREATURE_WIDTH, Creatures.DEFAULT_CREATURE_HEIGHT);
  
  bounds.x = 32;
  bounds.y = 32;
  bounds.width = 92;
  bounds.height = 96;
  
  //Animations
  animDino = new Animation(100, Assets.DerpDino);
 }

 @Override
 public void tick() {
  //Animations
  animDino.tick();
  //Movement
  getInput();
  move();
  handler.getGameCamera().centerOnEntity(this);
 }
 
 private void getInput(){
  xMove = 0;
  yMove = 0;
  
  if(handler.getKeyManager().up)
   yMove = -speed;
  if(handler.getKeyManager().down)
   yMove = speed;
  if(handler.getKeyManager().left)
   xMove = -speed;
  if(handler.getKeyManager().right)
   xMove = speed;
//  if(handler.getKeyManager().jump)
   //what to type here???
 }

 @Override
 public void render(Graphics g) {
  g.drawImage(getCurrentAnimationFrame(), (int) (x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()), (int) (y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()), width, height, null); 
 
//  g.setColor(Color.red);
//  g.fillRect((int) (x + bounds.x - handler.getGameCamera().getxOffset()),
//    (int) (y + bounds.y - handler.getGameCamera().getyOffset()),
//    bounds.width, bounds.height);
 }
 
 private BufferedImage getCurrentAnimationFrame(){
  return animDino.getCurrentFrame();
 }
 
}
```

Comment: What engine are you using? In the end, you're going to need another variable on your player, `velocity`, that keeps track of the players current speed. Jumping (`handler.getKeyManager().jump`) would change it to a positive y speed. Gravity would be decreasing the `velocity.y` by a constant amount every `tick()` (an acceleration, not based on mass) except when you're touching the ground. Basically, you need a simple physics system in your game, but depending on the engine you're using it might be there for you, I just couldn't find anything regarding `com.vescorpel` on the internet.

Comment: eclipse is my engine and VescorSpel is my weebly website name.

Comment: Are you talking about the [eclipse Java IDE](www.eclipse.org)? In that case, this is a custom engine then? If so, you're going to need to add a physics subsystem for your engine that handles velocities, collisions, forces, etc on your objects.

Comment: If you want to discuss it more, join this room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48290/from-comments-of-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating physics in your game (not only gravity) is a topic that Glenn Fiedler covered in a great manner on his website : [Game Physics in Games](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/integration-basics/)

Reading this will give you all the answers you are looking for.